# How do I check attributes of an object passed as parameter to a service mocked with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am new to Mockito and I am not able to test this scenario:

I want to test a ws controller that takes a json string, parses it and calls a method from a service with the resulted object.
I have decided to mock the service dependency with Mockito and I am trying to verify that the correct method from this mock is called with the correct parameter.

I think the problem is that the verify method compares the references of the two objects. Is there a way to compare certain attributes of the object passed as parameter? 
Is there a solution other than overriding the equals method of the "DummyObj" from the example?

*short recap: the controller.recive( json ) method takes a string and calls service.onMessage( resultedObj ) with the parsed obj as param. the onMessage method is not returning anything. *

The test looks like this:

```java
@Test
public void test() {
    DummyObj dummyObj = new DummyObj();
    String dummyObjJson = new Gson().toJson(dummyObj);

    controller.recive(dummyObjJson);

    verify(mockedService).onMessage(dummyObj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is using [ArgumentMatchers.argThat](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#argThat(org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher))

```
verify(mockedService)
  .onMessage(ArgumentMatchers.argThat(obj->obj.getName().equals(dummyObj.getName())));
```

And the another way is using [ArgumentCaptor](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.9/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html)

```
 ArgumentCaptor<DummyObj> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(DummyObj.class);
verify(mock).doSomething(argument.capture());
assertEquals("John", argument.getValue().getName());
```